# Api call finds already deleted documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've two endpoints: one that delete product document and one that retrieve the document.

After I delete the document throught by Id, the GET api call return me already the document even if it's deleted and It's not present on MongoDb.

Response of DELETE call returns `{ deletedCount: 1 }`

Here code of GET product:

```js
exports.getSingleProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;

  Products.findById(id).populate({ path: 'internalColor' }).then(result => {
    if(result && result.visible == true) {
      res.status(200).json(result)
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: 'product_not_found',
        id: id
      })
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(404).json({
      message: 'error_operation: ' + err,
      id: id
    })
  });
}
```

Here code of DELETE product:

```js
exports.deleteDefinallySingleProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;

  console.log(id)

  Products.deleteOne({ id: id }).then(result => {
    if(result) {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'deleted_product'
      });
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(404).json({
      message: 'error_operation: ' + err
    })
  })
}
```

Products Model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const options = {
    timestamps: true
}

const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    externalUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    imgUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    brand: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    visible: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
}, options);


const Product = mongoose.model('Products', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

Comment: Please also include the source code for the model.

Comment: did you check if it was really deleted into database? Did you use some kind of "soft-delete"?

Comment: From the official [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteOne) "Model.deleteOne() - Deletes the first document that matches conditions from the collection. It returns an object with the property deletedCount" Please log result.deletedCount to confirm if the product was deleted

Comment: @RobertKawecki I have include model, thank you

Comment: @The_flash thank you for your comment. I have include log

Comment: Is the server side code of the GET endpoint called after the deletion? The file could be cached client side (e.g. in the browser) from the first call and instead of calling again, it serves it from the cache

Comment: @A_A yes, the code is server side. But the problem is during the implementation test thorught Postman (I haven't implemented yet on client side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error that you are facing is caused by a typo in your code.

```js
exports.deleteDefinallySingleProduct = (req, res, next) => {
 ...

  Products.deleteOne({ id: id }).then(result => {
    if(result) {
      // this code will run always
      console.log(result) // will show { n: 0, ok: 1, deletedCount: 0 },
      // That is, this section of code will run always despite of delete count being 0 or more due to the request to be excecuted successfully.
      ...
}
```

The correct implementation is here:

```js
exports.deleteDefinallySingleProduct = (req, res, next) => {
 ...

  Products.deleteOne({ _id: id }).then(result => {
   
      ...
}
```

This is because by default mongooose use _id representing the document id, unless create a custom id in the schema which you didn't do.